# Expect script to read IP from hosts.txt and commands from commands.txt and implement script further to grab general info of server

Tags: scripting, expect

There are two files:
1.hosts.txt
2.commands.txt

I intent to write a script to grab 1st IP from hosts.txt and run 1st command from commands.txt.
Then,script goes to 2nd IP form hosts.txt and run 2nd command from commands.txt

is it possible?if,yes how?

i tried writing below expect script but failed to get desired output

**Below is the code and the optput**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#This Script will Commission Multiple Gateway with TUI

set fid [open ./hosts.txt r]
set contents [read -nonewline $fid]
close $fid

# Get the commands to run, one per line
set q [open "commands.txt"]
set commands [split [read $q] "\n"]
close $q

foreach host [split $contents "\n"] {

#Loggin into the Gateway as Normal user

spawn -noecho ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=No expect@$host
expect "password:"
send "$pass\n"

#foreach commands [split $commands "\n"] 

# Iterate over the commands
foreach cmd $commands {
        expect "% "
        send "$cmd\r"
}
}

**the output of this script:**
script logs into the server one by on which are there in hosts.txt but run all the commands mentioned in commands and not as i want which is stated above

Note:i set variables for username passowrd which i mention in along with ./ while executing command so leva that part
```

Answer (score 1):

---

This is where you'll use Tcl's "multi-list" [`foreach`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/foreach.htm) formulation:

```
set hosts [split $contents \n]

foreach host $hosts cmd $commands {
    # handle unequal size lists
    if {$host eq "" || $cmd eq ""} then continue
    
    spawn -noecho ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=No expect@$host
    expect "password:"
    send "$pass\r"

    expect "% "
    send "$cmd\r"
    expect "% "
    send "exit\r"
    expect eof

    # or, instead of the above expect-send pairs, do
    #   spawn -noecho ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=No expect@$host $cmd
    #   send password
    #   expect eof
}
```